# How to write the following polynomial in $(1-\frac{x}{a}) (1-\frac{x}{b}) (1-\frac{x}{c}) (1-\frac{x}{d})$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, analysis

I was given the following problem:

Write the polynomial $f(x) = \frac{1}{24} \displaystyle \prod_{i \mathop = 1}^4 (x-i)$ in the form $(1-\frac{x}{a}) (1-\frac{x}{b}) (1-\frac{x}{c}) (1-\frac{x}{d})$

So far I have done this:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{24} \displaystyle \prod_{i \mathop = 1}^4 (x-i) = \frac{1}{24}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) 
= \frac{1}{24}(1-x)(2-x)(3-x)(4-x)
= (\frac{1-x}{1}) (\frac{2-x}{2}) (\frac{3-x}{3}) (\frac{4-x}{4})
= ({1-x}) (1-\frac{x}{2}) (1-\frac{x}{3}) (1-\frac{x}{4})$

EDIT: Seems like I got it, thanks for all the help!

Comment: **HINT**: Because you have a polynomial to the $4^{th}$ (even) power, then $\prod_{i=1}^4(x-i) = \prod_{i=1}^4(i - x)$

Comment: You've got an extra minus sign in the last step. Apart from that, split $24$ into $1\times 2\times 3\times4$ and take them inside the respective brackets.

Comment: @AritraDas I am factoring out the minus sign so I can write it in the way I wrote it.

Comment: @malcolm I get it, but you see, there are 4 minus signs and so effectively, you're taking out $(-1)(-1)(-1)(-1) = 1$ which is why you have an extra minus sign.

Comment: there will be 4 '-' signs coming out which will make it positive , you have made a mistake in the last step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{24}  \prod_{i  = 1}^4 (x-i)=\frac{1}{24}  \prod_{i  = 1}^4 \left((-i)(1-\frac{x}{i})\right)=\frac{1}{24}  \prod_{i  = 1}^4 (-i)\prod_{i  = 1}^4(1-\frac{x}{i})$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $x-i = i\left(\dfrac{x}{i}-1\right)=-i\left(1-\dfrac{x}{i}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

hint:roots of the polynomial have to be same , what are the roots of l.h.s and r.h.s and then compare